# Orbeon + jsf -> submit in selectonemenu

Tags: forms, jsf, javabeans, orbeon, xforms

I have a problem with `xforms`, how refresh only `rich:panel` when I choose value from `h:selectOneMenu` :

```
<!--<h:form> call bean but--> <form><!--open start page-->
    <h:selectOneMenu id="add" onchange="submit()" <!-- can't find context , error orbeon/java-->  >
    <!-- is not working <a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{bean.action}"/> -->

    <s:selectItems value="#{bean.List()}" var="message" itemValue="#{message}" label="#{message}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    </form>
```

more Code JSF :

```
<form>
<rich:panel styleClass="DocumentBody" id="documentPanel"
    name="panell" style="margin-top:10px; height:90px;">
    <f:facet styleClass="documentHeader" name="header"></f:facet>
    <div id="documentTest" class="actionButtons">
        <div style="clear: both; height: 15px; width: 60px" />
        <s:button id="addButton" value="#{messages['operation.save.button']}"
            action="#{actionBean.generateNewName()}" reRender="confirm"
            onclick="#{actionBean.generateNewName()};#{rich:component('confirm')}.show();return false;">
        </s:button>
        <s:button id="loadButton" value="#{messages['operation.load.button']}"
            action="#{actionBean.loadDraft()}" reRender="documentTests,documentPanel,loadButton" />
        <s:button id="deleteButton" value="#{messages['operation.delete.button']}"
            action="#{actionBean.deleteDraft()}" reRender="documentTests,documentPanel,deleteButton" />
    </div>
</rich:panel>
</form>
<h:form style="margin: 0;">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="messageTypeAdd"
        style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:-30px;margin-left:90px;"
        valueChangeListener="#{actionBean.documentTestChange}"
        enableManualInput="false" selectFirstOnUpdate="true"
        directInputSuggestions="true" onchange="submit()">

        <!-- submit() rerender all page, but i try refresh only modalPanel id="confirm" -->

        <s:selectItems value="#{actionBean.getdocumentTestList()}"
            var="message" itemValue="#{message}" label="#{message}" />

        <!--a4j and f:ajax is not work, i try update JSF 1.2 to 2.0 -->

    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
<rich:modalPanel id="confirm" autosized="true" width="300">
    <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
    <rich:messages style="color:red;" globalOnly="true" />
    <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
        <h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="#{messages['report.name.label']}" />
                <h:inputText id="newDraftNameInput" value="#{actionBean.newDraftName}"
                    valueChangeListener="#{actionBean.newDraftNameChange}">
                </h:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried

Comment: I think is to much code. I wanted to perform actions in a separate rich:panel on the same page . On the concurrently running orbeon validates and filters on the same time form . I do not know why exclude the effect a4j . SelectOneMenu submit to refresh the entire page, but when it is receiving context ( REST ) shall be null and page displays the error .

Comment: @user3750157 I don't see any XForms in the snippet you mentioned, or anything related to XForms or Orbeon Forms. Is this purely a JSF problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: Xform generated from the file , and orbeon including comrades. Exactly what form after generation have a page on which i want to add a few buttons and selectonemenu . Unfortunately, as in the question actions they do not work as expected .